# How to save the state of the Map view using angularjs and in JSON format?

Tags: json, angularjs, d3.js

I have a map created using D3. There are specific points as per place name. Those point are movable as per user convinience to create a better view using dragging and zoomming. I need to create a "saved view of the map" for the user using angularjs and save the data in JSON format.So that when the user comes back they can have the same view of the map again. I need to capture scaling, longitude, latitude and data associated with those specific points. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches: it depends on whether you want the state to be persisted on the server or only on the client.

The general workflow would be to:

1.
Create a JSON object that holds the state you want to persist
for ex:

```
var mapState = {
   center: [lat, long], // replace lat, long with your coordinates
   // more properties go here...
}
```

2. save the data to the server (you'll need a back-end for that) or save the data in the local storage (here's an example: http://yeoman.io/codelab/local-storage.html)
3. load the saved data on reload/when the user comes back